# How to display content of respective table cell on hover table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Maybe somewhat like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788131/show-table-cell-on-table-row-mouseover), but example in accepted seems not working.
I want to show here, Action button, on hovering the row. So when I hover to particular table row, so only that row's action button should be displayed and all others should be hidden.

So how can I achieve this? Is jQuery required or is it possible through Pure CSS?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Instance Id</th>
      <th width="150px">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="">Start</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="action">Start</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty straight-forward and can be done with CSS.

You want a hover on the `<tr>` element (i.e. `tr:hover`) to change the display property of a descendant (i.e. `.action`). So the selector to use would be `tr:hover .action`.

Here's the working snippet:

```css
.action {
  display: none;
}

tr:hover .action {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Instance Id</th>
      <th width="150px">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="action">Start</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="action">Start</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can read more about the descendant selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Comment: Nice answer, just to add. I prefer visibility: visible | hidden; to avoid CSS issues.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution Pure CSS:

```
.table tbody tr td a{
    display: none;
}

.table tbody tr:hover > td a{
    display: block;
}
```